# How to create vertical dashed line and triangle tooltip in Xamrin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am creating a history screen and need to make a dashed vertical line and a left arrow. 
I created a list of items that are populating the data but couldn't continue. I will leave below an image of the expected result and the way it is currently.

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks!

**Code**

```
        <ListView x:Name="timelineListView"
                  ItemTapped="timelineListView_ItemTapped"
                  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                  Margin="0, 15, 0, 0">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                              Margin="0, 0, 0, 20"
                              Padding="20, 0, 0, 0">

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.85*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- Tipo Histórico-->
                            <BoxView Color="{StaticResource CorBranco}"
                                     Grid.Row="0"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     WidthRequest="40"
                                     CornerRadius="200"
                                     HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

                            <Image Aspect="AspectFit"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Margin="-10, 0, 0, 0"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   Source="{Binding ImagemTipoHistorico}" />

                            <Frame Margin="0, 0, 35, 0"
                                   Padding="20, 10, 10, 10" 
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   CornerRadius="10" 
                                   HasShadow="True"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource CorBranco}">

                                <Frame.Effects>
                                    <effects:ShadowEffect Color="{StaticResource CorCinzaBordaFrame}"
                                                          Radius="0.1"
                                                          DistanceX="0"
                                                          DistanceY="4" />
                                </Frame.Effects>

                                <Grid Style="{StaticResource EstiloGrid}">

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <!-- Descrição Tipo Histórico -->
                                    <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           Text="{Binding DescricaoTipoHistorico}"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FonteFilsonSoftBlack}"
                                           TextColor="{StaticResource CorPreto}" />

                                    <!-- Horas -->
                                    <Label VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalOptions="End" 
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           FontSize="10"
                                           Text="{Binding HoraDataRealizado}"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FonteFilsonSoftBlack}"
                                           TextColor="{StaticResource CorCinzaClaro4}" />

                                    <!-- Nome PDV -->
                                    <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                           Margin="0, 5, 0, 0"
                                           FontSize="16"
                                           Text="{Binding NomePdv}"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource FonteFilsonSoftBlack}"
                                           TextColor="{StaticResource CorCinzaPadrao}" />
                                </Grid>

                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**Expected:**

[image]

**Currently:**

[image]

Comment: for the triangle, use an image adjacent to the frame

Comment: Both your requirement is possible using Skia sharp(drawing library by Microsoft). I have provided code in my answer below. The Arrow View can be easily achieved as stated by @Jason in above comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use skia sharp to achieve both of your requirements. But Jason's comment is more easier for the arrow.

Dashed lines [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/dots)

DashedLine.Xaml

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <skia:SKCanvasView
        PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface"/>
</ContentView.Content>
```

DashedLine.Xaml.cs

```
private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = SKColors.Gray,
            StrokeWidth = 3,
            PathEffect = SKPathEffect.CreateDash(new float[] { 10, 10 }, 20)
        };

        SKPath path = new SKPath();

        path.MoveTo(info.Width / 2, 0);
        path.LineTo(info.Width / 2, info.Height);

        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
    }
```

ArrowView.Xaml:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <skia:SKCanvasView
        x:Name="arrowView"
        PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface">
    </skia:SKCanvasView>
</ContentView.Content>
```

ArrowView.Xaml.cs

```
private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
            Color = SKColors.White,
            StrokeWidth = 1,
        };

        SKPath path = new SKPath();

        path.MoveTo(0, info.Height / 2);
        path.LineTo(info.Width, info.Height * 3 / 4);
        path.LineTo(info.Width, info.Height / 4);
        path.Close();

        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

Use the DashedLine and ArrowView in your case:

1.Add the DashedLine view to the same grid space as the BoxView

```
<local:DashedLines/>
<!-- Tipo Histórico-->
<BoxView Color="White"
     Grid.Row="0"
     Grid.Column="0"
     WidthRequest="40"
     CornerRadius="200"
     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

2.Add the ArrowView by creating a column to the left of your Frame view.

```
<local:DashedLines/>
                        <!-- Tipo Histórico-->
                        <BoxView Color="White"
                                 Grid.Row="0"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 WidthRequest="40"
                                 CornerRadius="200"
                                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

                        <Grid
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            ColumnSpacing="0"
                            Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <local:ArraowView/>
                        <Frame
                               Padding="0, 10, 10, 10" 
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               CornerRadius="10" 
                               HasShadow="True"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
```

UI result: (Requires changes in Padding and margin)

[image: Timeline listView]

Hope this could help you! Regarding the in first and last items, the dashes needs to be only half way. For this you could use some DataTemplateSelector

Comment: That was what I needed. Thank you!